# Split Edges doesn't work

Tags: modeling, edges

I found a hard surface modeling technique in the video below (link) but i have no idea how to make it work. Skip to the minute 28:00 of the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJbxu_GLMz0&list=WL&index=4&t=1583s

Please someone know how could this work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't use all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting and is considered rude.
Also don't make people watch a video to understand what you want, explain what you are looking for and post some images of the relevant steps.

Comment: Desolate. I didn't men to be rude. I was just trying to respect the typographical principle according to which titles should be written in capitals letters.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a default cube;

[image]

Add a Solidify and Bevel modifier;

[image]

Edit the cube, and add an edge loop;

[image]

Hit <kbd>v</kbd>, then <kbd>enter</kbd>;

[image]

Edit the Solidify thickness to a desired value;

[image]

Edit the cube, and add another loop cut, hit <kbd>v</kbd>, then <kbd>enter</kbd>;

[image]
[image]
[image]

Add in a bunch more, wherever you like;

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alexander, but it stil doesn't work. If i press V , and than ENTER nothing happen. If i press V and than ESC something similar to the dsired result happen but the geometry inside it becomes horrible. You know why this happen?

Comment: Can you share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/